# Does a SELECT FOR UPDATE incur performance cost if a row does not exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm performing a query where there is a high probability the row does not exist, but I do want to lock the row via a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` if it does exist. Would there be any performance hit from `SELECT FOR UPDATE` right away in the cases where the row doesn't exist?

My use case is on postgres if the DB affects the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no matching row, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` won't be any more expensive than plain 'SELECT'.